# Little boy with robotic gloves attached to one hand. What's the name of the show?

Tags: story-identification, robots, hard-sci-fi

He was wondering or exploring, I don't know. He came into a place like a crash scene with a big dead robot - not that big, a little bit bigger than a human - and the boy had some kind of pet or robot with him and he accidentally tried to put his hand in the dead robot's arm and it activated, then he couldn't get it out anymore. Later he learned the power of the robotic hand and that the hand held great power. The desert was like a plain and the place was not like a usual place.

Can you please let me know the show and episode name? I'll be glad if you can help me. He looked like a little or young boy to me, and the robotic hand was not that metal - it looked kind of like a glove with LEDs on it.

Comment: live-action or cartoon? was it in english? when did you watch it? do you remember any names of characters?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/164368/looking-for-a-t-v-show-animation-boy-can-change-into-red-and-yellow-robot-w

Comment: I guess this isn't the classic 1942 SF novella _[Waldo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waldo_(short_story))_ by Robert A. Heinlein.  :(

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the right one, since it looks very metal, but *[EON Kid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eon_Kid)*? It features a young boy in a desert, finds a robot arm, sticks his hand in it. I have the part in the first episode where he puts his arm in embedded below:

He does also have a robotic dog, which also fits the question.

Comment: Thanks was looking for so long for this series. Forgot its name. Got it here.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's [*Heroman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroman). I was searching for the same show though

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some more matching details?