# Looking for a T.V. show - Animation - Boy can change into red and yellow robot with an arm blaster

Tags: story-identification, tv

Don't have any images, but I'll try my best to describe from memory. It's an animated kids show that I used to watch on Netflix. I don't remember the plot, but the main character, if I remember correctly, was a boy who could change into a red and yellow robot with an arm blaster. His helmet looked like a bicycle helmet if that's anything.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Great start. Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and edit in any more details.

Comment: First off, did it look like traditional animation or computer graphics? Do you remember how he got the suit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you be thinking of *[Eon Kid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eon_Kid)*, the English translation of the Korean cartoon, *아이언 키드* (Iron Kid)? He does have a red-and-yellow suit, a blaster, and the head does look a bit like a bike helmet. And it was available on Netflix until 2013.

[image: Image of Marty from Eon Kid]

> Marty is the lead character of the series. While scavenging for robot parts to sell he finds the Fist of Eon and puts it on, although unwillingly. Marty later discovers that he is a direct descendant of Eon, who 100 years prior to the series start defeated the General and ended the Robot War. Endowed with the power of the fist he must fight the evil forces of the general. He was originally named Iron kid in the original Korean version. Marty is the last descendant of the Eon family and is also the last heir of Eon. He is the final carrier of the Fist. He's shown to possess a natural talent for fighting and grows stronger as the series goes on.

Here's the opening.

Comment: I was familiar with it because I provided it as an answer at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94775/little-boy-with-robotic-gloves-attached-to-one-hand-whats-the-name-of-the-show/94826#94826. If this is the answer, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: wow, beat me too it, just spent 15 minutes trawling through old netflix toons. +1

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt: As I said, I was vaguely familiar with it, although I still had to spend some time finding my answer. :-D