Old cartoon show about a boy who wore a red gauntlet
The main character was a young boy who had a red colour theme and wore a red gauntlet like thing which transformed him. At first only his arm but in later episodes his whole body.
He had a middle age guy as a mentor/side kick.
The kids father was killed by the main villain for his gauntlet.

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/193796/animated-series-whose-main-character-wears-a-red-gauntlet-on-his-arm?

In roughly which year did you watch this? And was the animation hand-drawn (2D) or computer-generated (3D)?

If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

The gauntlet is grey, not red, but the rest of the plot matches Eon Kid, also released as Iron Kid.


It's set in an After the End Far East world, where a boy named Marty finds an Ancestral Weapon, the Fist of Eon, which adheres to is arm and grants him the power of becoming the Iron Kid. Along a diverse array of companions, he will face the forces of the evil General in a war for the fate of the world.

As you can see, the form he transform into does have a lot of red (although the gauntlet stays grey). Marty is accompanied by Master Zhang, and old martial arts master, and Charlie, an administrator and contemporary of Marty's father. And indeed, Marty's father was killed by the General to try to gain access to the gauntlet.
Intro




If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/164368/looking-for-a-t-v-show-animation-boy-can-change-into-red-and-yellow-robot-w
